# Save TypeScript class object to Firestore using the Node.js Admin SDK

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, es6-map

I am trying to set data in a Firestore document from an object of a TypeScript class -

```
class Quest {

    id: number = Date.now();

    index: number = 0;

    quest: string[];
    options = new Map<string, string[]>();  

    goals: string[];
    
}
```

To convert the class to JSON -

```
questDocRef.set(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(quest)));
```

This sets all the fields in the quest doc except the Map field named options.

What would be a good way to achieve this?

Comment: JSON does not support ES2015's `Map`, `Set`, `WeakMap`, and `WeakSet`. It supports two types of aggregations: objects and arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore does not understand JavaScript ES6 Map type objects.  It only understands the native types used with JSON: null, string, number, boolean, object, array.

Instead of a Map, consider using an object.  Simply populate it with the fields and values you want to store in the document, and that will become a map type field in the document.

```
class Quest {

    id: number = Date.now();

    index: number = 0;

    quest: string[];
    options: { [key: string]: string[] } = {};

    goals: string[];
    
}
```

The type shown here will require that all `options` object keys are strings and all values are string arrays.